# I want to create a bootstrap gallery that users can upload to

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, upload, content-management-system, gallery

I am building a minecraft website for my server, the website is mainly built using the bootstrap api, I want to have a gallery on the website that trusted players can login and upload screenshots and have them automatically added to the gallery. Im guessing I need some sort of CMS, I am hoping to achieve something that looks like this http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/ but some way to upload pictures into it

Answer (score 0):

## **Carousel**

If you are wanting carousels then I seriously recommend you use http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html Owl Carousel, there are so many different ways you can get your images displayed. Plus the main reason I recommend it is because it is build using bootstrap so integrating the CSS into your actual site wouldn't be too much on an issue.

I wound go into much detail because there are so many different varieties of carousels you can load so it would be pointless explaining it all when it is all on their site. They explain it really well on the more **HOW TO** tab so check that out.

## **Lightbox**

And for your full gallery lightbox I would reccomend using this JavaScript over at http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/?u=9 He provides some really clean and professional output.

Plus the best thing is you can include it by simply using

`<script src="http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/lightbox.js"></script>`

and then you will want to make sure you include the jquery to ensure it loads fine

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`

You will want to load the JS at the bottom of the page so it doesn't decrease performance. And for the love of god LOAD THE JQUERY BEFORE ANY OTHER JS or your scripts will just fail.

At the top of the page load in the css:
`<link href="http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Then will obviously need the HTML code onto your site using something like:

`<a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>`

## **Login System**

I am not going to explain this here. As I don't have enough reputation to include more than two links yet. But you would need to use an SQL login and make sure that is is secure as well. Feel free to send me a message and I will write out a post for you on StackOverflow on how to make it all work.

## **Final Notes**

The good thing about the Owl Carousel and Lightbox is that I have used them running off the same Jquery which is great. I also know that loading in scripts and css externally can be slow and has its downsides. But I am just trying to help you get straight to the point if you want to load it in normally by loading the resources from your webserver then follow the guides on their site.

You can make the SQL link up with a login system, yes, that's one thing. But allowing users to upload their own images and your site distributing them is a completely different thing which will both take quite a while to get done and ensure that they work how they should.

Anyway, I hope this really does help and I have gone into a lot of detail to hopefully cover as much as possible. If you have any questions what so ever then feel free to comment below and I will get back to use as soon as I see it. If you need some more guided help then I can help you over messaging but I like to keep all resources public. :)

Thanks,
Luke

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know how to make a Carousel just fine(one of the great features of using bootstrap) and I also have the ability of creating a simple mysql login system, as well as a solution for uploading. my problem and the whole reason for the question is for users to be able to upload their own images into the gallery without me having to go through and hand code each and every image into the page. Also I dont want to integrate wordpress