# is there a way to create smooth gwt bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, gwt, carousel

I am using GWT bootstrap to create my project layout. I think there is a way to create smooth carousel animation with mere bootstrap js and css. I have created simple carousel in my main page but it is not sliding smoothly. here is my native query:

```
public native void flipName(Element e) /*-{
    $wnd.jQuery(e).carousel({ interval: 10000, easing:'linear'});
}-*/;
```

and i have override default css of bootstrap:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
-webkit-transition: 5s linear left !important;
-moz-transition: 5s linear left !important;
-o-transition: 5s linear left !important;
transition: 5s linear left !important;}
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. my html classes are created in respect of css.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are wanted to load this through your own code. But I have just wrote out a response for something similar [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861804/i-want-to-create-a-bootstrap-gallery-that-users-can-upload-to/23868727#23868727) for someone who was looking for a carousel.

The GWT Carousel is a great resource with a lot of cool widgets. But I recommenced at least taking a look at the owl carousel. If you insist on using GWT then I can take a further look into it for you.

Luke

Comment: I have seen the owl carousel, but i do not have another choice as the project is already is over. if there is an integration of owl carousel with GWT, then, it would be great. Anyway, Thanks for the answer.